# How to group a vector of pairs of strings by first string?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector containing pairs of strings:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> list;
```

I want to group the `list[n].second` strings that have the same `list[n].first`

```
const size_t nbElements = list.size();
for (size_t n = 0; n < nbElements ; n++)
{
    const string& name = list[n].first;
    const string& type = list[n].second;
}
```

---

Consider this example:

```
(big; table) (normal; chair) (small; computer) (big; door) (small; mouse)
```

would result to:

```
(big; table, door) (normal; chair) (small; computer, mouse)
```

---

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @leemes you mean a `std::multimap`, but yeah, would be the easiest solution. Oh wait, you mean a `std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>`, yeah, should work, too.

Comment: @ChristianRau Oh, of course `std::multimap`, not `map<...,vector...>`. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

---

Example:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // define original data
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > v = 
            {{"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"b", "a"}, {"b", "d"}, {"c", "e"}};

    // populate map
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > grouped;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        grouped[(*it).first].push_back((*it).second);
    }

    // output        
    for (auto it = grouped.begin(); it != grouped.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << boost::format("(%s: %s)\n")
                % (*it).first 
                % boost::algorithm::join((*it).second, ", ");
    }
}
```

[The output is:](http://liveworkspace.org/code/8YOMq%240)

```
(a: b, c)
(b: a, d)
(c: e)
```

---

Note, this code makes use of C++11 features (initializer lists, auto keyword). Have a look at the linked example above for the successful compilation.

In order to compile this yourself, make sure that the compiler you use supports these features or replace them with the appropriate C++03 equivalents.

For example, here are the iterator types (that are beautified using the `auto` keyword in above code):

```
// the iterator on the vector `v`
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >::iterator it_v;

// the iterator on the map `grouped`
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::iterator it_grouped;
```

Comment: `std::multimap` is made for this. (Of course your solution is OK too)

Comment: @leemes I regarded this to be more like a case of _store multiple values to one key_ instead of _store multiple entries having the same key_. I find the multimap a bit cumbersome for some tasks.

Comment: i get errors for (auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it) { --  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int -- error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'int'

Comment: @tchike this code makes use of features of C++11 (initializer lists, auto keyword). Make sure that the compiler you use supports them or replace them with the appropriate iterator types.

Comment: @moooeeeep I see, but I couldn't make it work. Can you please replace them? Thanks.

Comment: i replaced the iterators, now i get this error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 4):

You may want a multimap.

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::string> items;
items.insert("Big", "Chair");
items.insert("Big", "Table");
items.insert("Small", "Person");


for(auto i = items.begin(); i!=items.end; i++)
{
  std::cout<<"["<<i->first<<" , "<<i->second<<"]"<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
[Big, Chair]
[Big, Table]
[Small, Person]
```