# How to group a vector pair by the second value efficiently?

Tags: c++

I am trying to group the pair vector `vector<pair<int,int>>` by the second value of it. For example, if the pair is `v0 : (0,1),(1,1),(3,2),(4,2),(5,1)`. I want to get two outputs. The first one is the unique element of the second elements, which is

```
vector<int> v2={1,2};
```

The second is groups of the first elements, which could be

```
vector<vector<int>>v1;
v1[0]={0,1,5};
v1[1]={3,4};
```

How to achieve this in a efficient way? Do I need to sort the `v0` by the second element at first before the `group` process? Does `std::map` is a faster way? Not only the method, I also concern about the speed. Because my `v0` is a very long and unsorted triangle mesh vertices index list. Any suggestion will be appreciate.
Updated, I found one solution similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218488/how-to-group-a-vector-of-pairs-of-strings-by-first-string). It is in an unsorted way. I have no idea about its speed.

```
map<int, vector<int> > vpmap;
    for (auto it = v0.begin(); it != v0.end(); ++it) {
        vpmap[(*it).second].push_back((*it).first);
    };
```

in which, `vpmap.first` is corresponding to `v2`; and `vpmap.second` is corresponding to `v1`.

Comment: A set and multimap (or the unordered versions) might be helpful.

Comment: `std::sort` may also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a reasonably performant way of getting the exact data structures you're looking for. Be sure you pre-allocate the vectors since you know the size, and use move iterators to avoid unnecessary copying:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v0;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1;
v0.reserve(vpmap.size());
std::transform(vpmap.begin(), vpmap.end(), std::back_inserter(v0), [](auto p) { return p.first; });
v1.reserve(vpmap.size());
std::transform(make_move_iterator(vpmap.begin()), make_move_iterator(vpmap.end()), std::back_inserter(v1), [](auto p) { return p.second; });
```

If you can loosen your constraints, do think about big-picture optimizations like "do I need to transform all this data?"

But once you have something reasonable, stop worrying about the fastest techniques or containers or whatever, and start measuring with a profiler. Sometimes the stuff you worry about winds up being a non-issue and there are non-obvious costs that stem from your problem domain and input data and accumulation of code

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer. You pointed out my major problem in my mind, not only in these specific codes.  Could you explain a bit on the "profiler"? Do you mean a timer? Do you have some related functions to suggest?

Comment: A profiler is a tool that monitors the execution of a program, and tells you about its performance. It can tell you how much memory is being used by each portion (memory profiling), or how much time is spent in each part of your program (time profilling). It's great for identifying memory leaks or bottlenecks. `gprof` and `valgrind` are popular profilers on Linux. I think there's one built into MSVC, but I've never used it. You can also benchmmark (using a timer to measure execution), but stick to high-level app operations, as little experiments can be misleading without wider context.